# git status uses wrong path

Tags: git, path

I am new to git but I have been using it successfully in one of my projects. I came back to my project after a while and my git seems broken for some reason.

I am working on a Windows machine using powershell. My project is the following path:

When I use `git status` such as:

```
PS D:\...\03 Projects\05 Web-Development\Projects\demoproject> git status
```

I get the following:

```
fatal: Invalid path 'D:/.../03 Projects/09 Web-Development': No such file or directory
```

I don't understand that. `git status` checks a wrong path here? How is that possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey @Stefano! I think you are new to StackOverflow. Could you be a bit more verbose with the question in the sense that you provide a path to the project you are talking about?

Comment: Can you post the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` ? It will tell you where `git` thinks the root of your repo is located.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Problem just now.
Reason was that I accidentally added a remote to the shown invalid path.

To make thinks worse, this was not done in the the actual git repo but in a new git repo in a subfolder.

So in order to fix this error:

1. Check that all the remote configured are pointing to valid git repos
2. Check that there aren't any git repos in subfolder of your main repo and if they are, check 1 again.
3. Remove all remotes that do not point to a valid git repo.

Note as described by LeGEC, use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to determine where the top most git is and check from there.